# What is Unicast DNS and how does it differ from other kinds of DNS?

Tags: networking, dns, network-programming

1. What are the other types of DNS available?
2. How does it makes difference in resolving host names?

Answer (score 4):

There is unicast and anycast DNS. For clients they are indistinguishable, if only you don't measure time needed for a name resolve. Unicast DNS is an old and simple installation type: your have one primary DNS server which is physically located somewhere. So it may take much time for packets to travel over a globe to that server. Anycast DNS is a new installation type. Instead of one server you have many servers in different spots on the Earth, but that servers respond to the same IP address. And requests are routed to the closest server. So response time can be much less.

Comment: Thank you Alex. how can we find the network we are connected to is the Unicast or any cast DNS?

Comment: You don't need to know that for two reasons. The first is that it is implementation details of DNS which are not meant to be visible to clients. The second: DNS servers can't store full information about all domains in internet. So they query each other to get answer. You are connected to one DNS server, but it relays your requests to others and some of them may be unicast and others anycast.